# Laravel 5.2 Валидатор

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день товарищи. Подскажите кто в курсе как в laravel добавить в класс validator больше чем 1 уникальное поле. Если допустим у меня уникальные поля используются в связке с ( например серия и номер карты).

```
 return Validator::make($data, [
                'serial'     => 'required|min:3|unique:cards,serial',
                'number'     => 'required|min:8|max:8|regex:/[0-9]{8,8}/',
                'date_close' => 'required',
            ]);
```

Пробовал так но не помогает, все равно выбивает ошибку при первом же вхождении серийника, и даже не доходит до проверки номера. А по идее должно ругаться только когда оба значения в строке совпадают.

```
return Validator::make($data, [
            'serial'     => 'required|min:3|unique:cards,serial',
            'number'     => 'required|min:8|max:8|unique:cards,number|regex:/[0-9]{8,8}/',
            'date_close' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая штатная возможность:

```
public function rules()
{
    $currentId = $this->route()->parameter('table_name') ?: 'NULL';
    $serial = (int)$this->serial ?: 'NULL';
    return [
        'number' => 'unique:table_name,number,'
            // Для текущей записи проверку не делаем
            . $currentId . ',id,'
            // Уникальность в рамках серии
            . 'serial,' . $serial,
    ];
}
```

Если по какой-то причине не подходит, то можно попробовать использовать [этот пакет](https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator) и правило:

```
'serial' => 'unique_with:your_table,cards'
```